# What is required to raise my electric meter?

Tags: electrical, meter

I’m planning to do a 150 amp to 200 amp panel upgrade.  The outside meter is underground fed, and is also about 30” on center above grade. Install was 1972

I’m hearing that the meter be deemed too low.  What are some options to raise it without having to run new underground feeder lines?  Can there be a junction box for #2 wire? Fused or unfusd?

Comment: Most meters are owned by the power company and usually they have complete control on what you can do, usually just look.  Ask them.

Comment: Who is your electrical utility?

Comment: Who are you "hearing" this from?

Comment: As it is your question lacks many important details that would help someone answer it for you.  Please edit your question and add those details.

Answer (score 6):

You'll probably want an electrician for this. There's some major reasons why

1. Most utilities do not provide you a meter box. They will happily run wire to a meter box and stick a meter in for you, but that's it.
2. Some meter boxes have a main panel attached. If this is the case, you might be needing to move a lot of wires. And if you're touching the main panel, you might want to replace it with a newer model. That 1972 box won't last forever.
3. You'll have to have a utility disconnect (unless you want to [YOLO disconnect live wires yourself](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KT2vEC3ihz8), which is **extremely dangerous**). An electrician will know whom to contact for that, and save you some hassle in coordinating it
4. If the utility does this, they'll want to know why. This might involve them notifying any municipal authorities who might want to come out and look. And they could demand the utility not hook you back up until *everything* is brought up to code. If you don't know all your local regulations, an electrician almost certainly will.

Comment: More comprehensive than mine was. Re (4) that can be **very** expensive - let sleeping dogs lie...

Comment: I had to bite this bullet when I went to add a subpanel last year and couldn't get anything into [my old main panel](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/218582/55930). The city came out and "inspected" the electricians "repairing" my main box (they literally looked at it and left, just like the main electrician thought they would). I cannot imagine what would have happened if I had had to deal with the inspector myself.

Comment: My Dad had a similar case, inspectors came out to check his wiring in the property (that I had been doing over time) and they said "who did this"? When he told them, they said it was far better than the local electricians and were impressed - so was I as they tested all the earth continuity etc.